# Error in displaying jQuery/JS multiple pop ups

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, popup

3 scripts for 3 pop ups, I am almost certain there is a better way to structure these and turn 3 scripts into one, achieving a result of only having one pop up open at a time. All suggestions are welcome.

**Issue**

As a single pop-up opens the other closes which is not the intended

**Code in Context**

```
<div class="col-sm-4 column">
            <div class="popup-trigger">
                <img src="AW16/pages/JA2305_s02-184.jpg?$staticlink$" alt="The Campaign: AW16" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
                <div class="popup-new" >                    
      <span class="popup-btn-close">X</span>
    </div>                      
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 column">
            <div class="popup-trigger-b">         
                <img src="AW16/pages/JA2305_s01-034.jpg?$staticlink$" alt="The interview: Sam Rollinson" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
               <div class="popup-new-b" style="display:none">           
      <span class="popup-btn-close">X</span>
     </div>                    
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 column">
            <div class="popup-trigger-c">      

                <img src="AW16/pages/JA2305_s04-013.jpg?$staticlink$" alt="Tried & Tested: The Shirt Dress" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
               <div class="popup-new-c" style="display:none">          
      <span class="popup-btn-close">X</span>
    </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".popup-trigger").click(function () {
$(".popup-new").fadeIn(300);

});

$(".popup-new > span, .popup-new").click(function () {
$(".popup-new").fadeOut(300);
});
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".popup-trigger-b").click(function () {
$(".popup-new-b").fadeIn(300);

});

$(".popup-new-b > span, .popup-new-b").click(function () {
$(".popup-new-b").fadeOut(300);
});
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".popup-trigger-c").click(function () {
$(".popup-new-c").fadeIn(300);

});

$(".popup-new-c > span, .popup-new-c").click(function () {
$(".popup-new-c").fadeOut(300);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ all the code }

Comment: Yes but doesn't get around the issue of only one pop up being open at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a fair amount with CSS selectors (which work within $('')) and each loops provided by jQuery. Here is an example of one function which will manage the fading in and out of 3 seperate paragraph tags.

https://jsfiddle.net/oo80eqc4/3/

```
$("[class^='popup-trigger-']").on('click', function() {
  var letter = ($(this).attr('class'))
  var combined = ".popup-new-" + letter.substr(letter.length - 1)
  $("[class^='popup-new-']").not(combined).each(function() {
     $(this).fadeOut(300); 
  });
  $(combined).fadeToggle(300)
});
```

The following selects all elements with the class *starting with* 'popup-trigger-'.

```
$("[class^='popup-trigger-']")
```

I have also used, in this example, not to exclude the current "popup".

This code example is scalable, as it is independant on your numbering. I have not extensively tested it but I hope it's what you were after.

I don't think my code is directly usable within your example, but I have made it as clear as I can to help you on the way. [Here is a good resource](http://www.cheetyr.com/css-selectors) for CSS selectors with short explainations. Hope this helps.

Comment: great got it working, thanks for your answer! do you happen to know how i can close the pop up based on close 'popup-btn-close' or if clicked anywhere on the page?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oo80eqc4/4/ here's an updated Fiddle for you with the close button functionality - as for popup closing on outside click, I believe that would be possible via targetting "document" and checking to make sure the click did not originate within your popup.

Comment: do you know how i could implement that into this code, ive tried a few things from other questions with no success. this is a massive learning curve for me

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oo80eqc4/5/ this works for me, let me know if it's the correct functionality. It may be further condensable.

Comment: doesn't work for me - pop up just fade's in and out when. is there another way?

Comment: @user3767554 The code should demonstrate the core functionality that's needed. In the Fiddle it only removes when you aren't clicking within the paragraph tag. I'm afraid I can't be much more help without knowing your exact future format etc.